# Hibernate - Persisting child entity containing parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Getting errors while trying to persist child entity (MsgRetry) when trying to get an entity of parent entity (Msg) where the parent PK (msg_id) is the FK in the child entity.

Errors like: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

The parent entity, does not need to know about the child entity (at least i don't think it needs to, to work). Once the child entity is persisted I'm trying to also persist the parent entity. I can work around this by not having the parent entity in the child entity and the call the associated repositories. However, I don't think it's as clean as what I'm attempting but obviously more difficult/ complex.

Thanks for any advice on best practices or how to achieve this if this is a good solution.

tables:

| msg |  |
| --- | --- |
| msg_id | pk |
| msg_status | msg_status |

| msg_retry |  |
| --- | --- |
| msg_id | fk |
| count |  |
| timestamp |  |

model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="msg")
public class Msg {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "msg_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = generationtype.sequence, generator = "msg_id_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "msg_id_seq_gen", sequencename = "msg_id_seq", allocationsize = 1)
    private Long msgId;
    
    @Column(name = "msg_status", nullable = false)
    private String msgStatus;
    
    ...
    
    //getters setters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msg_retry")
public class MsgRetry implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7637385223556379976L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "msg_id")
    private Long msgId;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="msg_id", referencedColumnName = "msg_id")
    private Msg msg;
    
    @Column(name = "count")
    private Long count;
    
    @Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private Date timestamp;
    
    
    
    public MsgRetry() {
    }

    public MsgRetry(Msg msg, Long count) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.count = count;
    }
    
    public MsgRetry(Long msgId, Long count) {
        this.msgId = msgId;
        this.count = count;
    }
    
    public Msg getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(Msg msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
```

```
@Repository
public interface MsgRetryRepository extends JpaRepository<MsgRetry, Long>{

}
```

```
@Test
    public void testSaveMsgByMsgIdRetry() {
        
        msgRetryRepository.deleteAll();
        List<Msg> msgs = msgRepository.findAll();
        
        MsgRetry msgRetry = new MsgRetry(msgs.get(0).getMsgId(), 1L);
        
        msgRetry = msgRetryRepository.save(msgRetry);
        assertNotNull(msgRetry.getMsg());  // fails to load Msg entity
        LOG.info("msgRetry: {}", msgRetry);
    }
```

```
@Test
    public void testSaveMsgRetryByMsg() {
        
        msgRetryRepository.deleteAll();
        List<Msg> msgs = msgRepository.findAll();
        
        MsgRetry msgRetry = new MsgRetry(msgs.get(0), 1L);
        
        msgRetry = msgRetryRepository.save(msgRetry);
        assertNotNull(msgRetry.getMsg());
        LOG.info("msgRetry: {}", msgRetry);
    }
```

Errors out: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): msgtest.MsgRetry;

Answer (score 0):

First, straighten out your IDs for `MsgRetry`.  The FK should be good enough.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msg_retry")
public class MsgRetry {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "msg_id")
    private Msg msg;
    
    @Column(name = "count")
    private Long count;
    
    @Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private Date timestamp;
    
    public Msg getMsg() { return msg; }
         
    public void setMsg(Msg msg) { this.msg = msg; }
}
```

Next, be sure `MsgRetryRepository` is properly sub-classed:

```
public interface MsgRetryRepository extends CrudRepository<MsgRetry, Msg>
{
  // Empty for now
}
```

Lastly, query the `MsgRetry` in the right way:

```
public class BizLogic {

    MsgRetryRepository retryRepo
    
    public MsgRetry retry(Msg msg, String msgStatus) {
    
        MsgRetry mr = retryRepo.findById(msg);        
        if (mr !=null) {
            // XXX I cannot tell from your logic what you are doing here.
            retryRepo.save(mr);
        }   
    }
}
```

What is your persistence layer?  Maybe you can turn on debugging and visit the logs to see what is happening under the hood.

Comment: I Edited the code posted along with the repository code. It's not clear to me if I need to use @Id in the MsgRetry Entity where the msg_id is a FK from the Msg table. Does the MsgRetry need it's own PK or can it's PK be a FK from another table (sorry little lost on this)